# stack vuetify elements in one page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vue-router, vuetify.js

Using vuetify, how can I make two UI components show up on one singular page?  I have tried combining elements within one   bracket and got error messages.  When stacking components in separate   only thee bottom template appears in the front end.  Is there a way two stack UI components using vue-router?

edit:  my goal is to place two ui components such as photo grid and carousel  from vuetify on top each other to create a print out similar to this screenshot  [mash-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0VRI.jpg).

This is the code that produces my current localhost printout [code sample of stacking templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YxqlT.jpg) and the [localhost printout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6qeo.jpg).

```
 <template>
 <v-layout>
<v-flex xs12 sm6 offset-sm3>
  <v-card>
    <v-container grid-list-sm fluid>
      <v-layout row wrap>
        <v-flex
          v-for="n in 9"
          :key="n"
          xs4
          d-flex
        >
          <v-card flat tile class="d-flex">
            <v-img
              :src="`https://picsum.photos/500/300?image=${n * 5 + 10}`"
              :lazy-src="`https://picsum.photos/10/6?image=${n * 5 + 10}`"
              aspect-ratio="1"
              class="grey lighten-2"
            >
              <v-layout
                slot="placeholder"
                fill-height
                align-center
                justify-center
                ma-0
              >
                <v-progress-circular indeterminate color="grey lighten-5"></v-progress-circular>
              </v-layout>
            </v-img>
          </v-card>
        </v-flex>
      </v-layout>
    </v-container>
  </v-card>
  </v-flex>
</v-layout>

<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item
    v-for="(item,i) in items"
    :key="i"
    :src="item.src"
  ></v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
</template>
```

Comment: You would need to posts some code showing what you have done and what you are expecting.

Comment: Please include the code **in the question itself**. Make sure to only include the minimal code required to reproduce the problem. You can style code by selecting the code in the editor, then clicking the `{}` button above the edit field. That said, a quick peek at your screenshot makes it appear you are not using valid SFC syntax. Make sure to only have one top-level `<template>` tag

Comment: @Sumurai8 if only one template is allowed how can two separate components or multiple  <layout>....</layout> be included in one page like the first screenshot posted.

Comment: I added code @Sumurai8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you have two template tags, if you move the content of the bottom template tag into the first one it should work. It should look something like this:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <v-layout>
            v-card etc...
        </v-layout>
        <v-carousel>
            v-carousel-item etc...
        </v-carousel>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    javscript code...
</script>
```

As @sumurai8 said, you should only have one top level template tag.

Comment: When I set the home.vue which is my default route up in the strucrture abovfe I get the following error   - Component template should contain exactly one root element. If you are using v-if on multiple elements, use v-else-if to chain them instead.

Comment: here's a link to the home.vue

Comment: You are missing the div I put in there, this is because you can only have one root level element. So place the div element right inside the template, then everything else inside the div. It should work